# How do I make a button to be set to show different view controllers depending on the day of the week?

Tags: ios, swift, button, uiviewcontroller, segue

How do I make a button to be set to show different view controllers depending on the day of the week? I mean, I have 7 viewcontroller, each with a different day. What I want is for them to show themselves by clicking on a button depending on the day.

Comment: Use different segues for different times. But I think you need to break this problem down further - where exactly are you having ht eproblem?

Comment: Do you really need 7 different view controllers? Why not just one that shows the proper data for a given day?

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with rmaddy. You could do 7 is different view controllers, but it would probably be easier to just configure your destination view controller based on the day of the week. Below are a couple of paths you could go. I would favor one view controller and configure it based on the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

I’d first of all start with extending the Date type with a weekday number function:

```
extension Date {
    func dayNumberOfWeek() -> Int? {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday], from: self).weekday 
    }
 }
```

Starting from that, as suggested you could either initialise **one** view controller with the day of the week, when performing the connected action, or create a specific view controller based on the day.